# Restart a loop in Fortran

Tags: algorithm, loops, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have an algorithm that looks like this:

```
10 WRITE (*,*) "Start"
DO I = 1, 10
WRITE (*,*) "Step"
IF(I .EQ. 5) then 
    go to 10
END IF
END DO
```

I want to restart the loop, when that if statement executes. However, I don't want to have to use a go to, I tried this:

```
10 WRITE (*,*) "Start"
DO I = 1, 10
WRITE (*,*) "Step"
IF(I .EQ. 5) then 
    I = 0; CYCLE
END IF
END DO
```

But then I get the error that I can't redefine the I variable, inside a  loop. So I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It seems like you are trying to learn, which is great. The answer you have accepted is *not* the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can suggest to ways of solving this issue: either use a while loop or a recursive function (highly depends on your actual algorithm). I am attaching a sample code for both cases (keep in mind that having variables with save qualifier is not the best idea, it's much better to do that with by passing variables as arguments to function - here it is used just for simplicity)

```
module functions

    implicit none

    integer :: restarted, save = 0
contains

    recursive subroutine restart_loop
        integer :: i

        do i = 1, 10
            print*, i
            if ( i == 5 .and. restarted < 5 ) then
                restarted = restarted + 1
                call restart_loop
                exit
            end if            
        end do        
    end subroutine restart_loop

    subroutine while_loop
        integer :: i = 1

        do while (i <= 10)
            print*, i
            if ( i == 5 .and. restarted < 5 ) then
                i = 1
                restarted = restarted + 1
            end if
            i = i + 1
        end do
    end subroutine while_loop
end module functions

program test_prog
    use functions

    implicit none

    call while_loop
end program test_prog
```

Comment: How do you place a subroutine, inside the main program? I always get errors when I do that (Unclassifiable statement at (1)). Subroutines only work for me when they're outside of the main program, or before the end statement :/

Comment: @efefef you don't, that is not possible in Fortran. As you can see here I am defining a module containing subroutines - in my opinion this is better then just defining the subroutine since it provides certain (limited) namespace functionality. Pay attention to "use functions" line - this is how you import a module for usage.

Comment: @efefef I strongly recommend you have a look at some of the fortran [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/topics) on  here. Putting subroutines in modules is a *very* good idea. Also see [this doc page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2203/program-units-and-file-layout/7202/internal-subprograms#t=201702031606390419663) for how to include a subroutine inside the program unit.

Comment: Any idea of how I could pass a variable like this to a subroutine?  character :: P(12,12)   I tried this                                                                     call sub(P), and the subroutine                                                                subroutine sub (P), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

A conceptually simple way to phrase this problem is: "I want to repeat a loop until it completes, where there is some abort condition".

This "repeat until it completes" is idiomatically a do construct with indeterminate iterations:

```
do
  ...  ! Our actions; we exit this outer loop when we are satisfied
end do
```

[This could also be phrased as a do-while loop.]

With the inner loop:

```
do
  do i=1,10
     ... ! A conditional statement which aborts the inner loop
     ... ! And some actions
  end do
  ! And once we're complete we exit the outer loop
end do
```

Now it's just a matter of handling "abort inner" and "exit outer".  Here `cycle` and `exit`:

```
outer: do
  print*, 'Start'
  do i=1,10
    print*, 'Step'
    if (...) cycle outer   ! Abort the inner loop
  end do
  exit outer  ! The inner loop completed, so we're done
end do outer
```

The outer loop is labelled so that the `cycle` statement in the inner loop can reference it.  Without that label the `cycle` will cycle the innermost loop containing it.

Answer (score -1):

Likely a typo here somewhere, but this has some other ideas in a "do while" sense.

i.e. One could poll something coming in.

```
... USE ISO... etc stuff.
REAL(KIND=C_FLOAT), DIMENSION(10) :: A
LOGICAL(KIND=C_BOOL)              :: Question1 = .TRUE.
LOGICAL(KIND=C_BOOL)              :: Question2 = .TRUE.
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT)               :: Index     = 0
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT)               :: I         = 5

WRITE(*,*)'Enter first index to skip:"
READ(*,*) I

Outer_Loop: DO WHILE (Question1)    ! .eq. .TRUE.

  Inner_Loop:  DO WHILE (Question2) ! .EQV. .TRUE.
    Index = Index + 1
    IF(Index > UBOUND(A,1)) THEN
      Question1 = .FALSE.
      Question2 = .FALSE.
      Exit
    ENDIF
    IF(Index == I) EXIT

    !Whatever like  A(INdex) = something....

  ENDDO Inner_Loop

  IF(Question1) THEN   !We must have more to possibly read or do...
    WRITE(*,*)'Do more? 1=yes, 0=No"
    READ(*,*) I
    IF(I == 1) THEN
      WRITE(*,*)'Enter next index to skip:"
      READ(*,*) I
      Question2 = .TRUE.
  !and one can do a reset of I=0 here, which then becomes I=1 the next time through the inner loop...
    ELSE
      Question1 = .FALSE.
      Question2 = .FALSE.
      EXIT
    ENDIF
  ELSE   !Must have gotten here to exit at the end of array?
    EXIT
  ENDIF
ENDDO Outer_Loop
```