# Can do loops have a label at the beginning

Tags: fortran

Currently I'm learning Fortran!
Can Do loop have `label` at the beginning as well as after `do` keyword as shown in the example??

```
program sample
implicit integer(a-z)
integer :: b = 20
10 do 15 i = 1, 5
      b = b + i
15 end do
if (b .eq. 35) go to 10
print *, b
end program
```

If not, what is the correct way to use the labels in the `do statement`(with example program)??

Comment: If you are learning Fortran, skip the `go to` statement. Do not use it. Only learn once you need to deal with old source codes that contain it. There are valid uses of `go to`, but one should ha e some real.experience first. Learn it much much later. Do not use numeric labels in `do` loops. The `go to` statement, outside of some limited contexts, is considered harmful.

Comment: Also please, please, please only use the Implicit statement in the form `Implicit None` (and closely related in f2018)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the current standard (F2018 6.2.5):

> Any statement that is not part of another statement, and that is not preceded by a semicolon in fixed form, may begin with a statement label

A DO statement like this is not part of another statement: yes it may be labelled.

That said, as you are using it as a `go to` target, you can consider that there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42026668/3157076) than labelling the DO statement.

And also, you should try to avoid that `15` label as well.  Not only is it redundant (the labelled statement is an `end do`) but the "labelled DO statement") is obsolescent and may be deleted from the standard. (The "nonblock DO construct", where the labelled statement is something other than `end do`, was deleted in Fortran 2018, so deletion isn't an empty threat.)

These points together give the program without any labels and with no `go to`:

```
  implicit none
  integer :: b, i

  b=20

  do
    do i = 1, 5
       b = b + i
    end do
    if (b .ne. 35) exit  ! or /= instead of .ne.
  end do

  print *, b
end
```

(I've also used `implicit none` and used an assignment for `b` instead of initialization.)

In general, while you can put labels in many places, there are very, very few places where you should use the labels.

---

"Part of another statement" makes lines like the following line bad:

```
if (.true.) 10 print *, "Hello"
```

The PRINT statement here is an action statement which is part of the IF statement. While the IF statement as a whole may be labelled, the PRINT statement is part of that statement and so may not be labelled.